# A construction on an infinite 2d grid, part 1

Tags: mathematics, geometry, construction

Recall [the classic old problem where we're asked whether a line segment of specific length can be constructed with compass and straightedge, given an initial line segment of length 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number)? We're going to do something similar here.

---

Imagine there is a 2-dimensional space that is infinite, with all integer coordinates (e.g `(5,3)` is an integer coordinate, `(7,-1.5)` is not) dotted. You are going to do the following construction to get a specific number:

- draw 4 line segments that start and end on a dot
- these 4 lines should enclose a *quadrilateral*, triangles are not counted. (You can't enclose more than one quadrilaterals anyway.)
- the quadrilateral enclosed should be of a specific type

And the area of the quadrilateral is the number you have constructed.

The question being asked is, given a specific type of quadrilateral being restricted, *what are the full set of numbers that we can construct this way*?

**In part 1, we're concerned with squares**.

Note that obviously, the vertices of the quadrilateral can be at non-integer coordinates. They are only required to be the *intersection* of two line segments.

---

Obvious, all square numbers are trivial to construct:

[image: 1]

Non square numbers, like `5` or `0.5`, requires a bit more effort:

[image: 5]

[image: 0.5]

Some numbers can be very hard to be constructed: e.g `0.8`(`4/5`) will take some effort, and more so for `1.8`(`9/5`). Meanwhile, are numbers like `3` or `1.5` even possible?

---

As a side note, [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing) might help you figuring out the construction, but don't expect to find every configuration this way.

Comment: Gut feeling says _nyy engvbany ahzoref_. Now someone just needs to provide a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number is constructible in this way iff:

> • It's rational, and can be factored into $\prod p_i^{a_i}$ such that:
>  • $p_i$ are primes, $a_i$ are integers (may be negative, but keep reading)
>  • If $p_i = 2$, then $a_i \geq -1$
>  • If $p_i = 4k + 1$ for some integer $k$, then $a_i$ can be any integer
>  • If $p_i = 4k + 3$, then $a_i \geq 0$ and $a_i$ must be even

Examples:

> This means that `1/2`, `5/2`, `4/5` are okay, while `1/4`, `2/3` are not.

Since phenomist already got most of the answer right, I will not duplicate it here. However, there is a probably important part phenomist missed:

> The numbers that can be written as $p^2 + q^2$ *are* those with prime factors $4k + 1$ or $2$. However, since we need $p$ and $q$ to be coprime, only at most one $2$ is allowed.
>
>  The general idea from now on is to write an integer, $x$, as the product of *gaussian primes*. A gaussian integer is a complex number with integer real and imaginary parts. A gaussian prime is one that cannot be written as the product of two non-$\pm 1$, non-$\pm i$ integers. As a corollary of the $p^2 + q^2 = 4k + 1$, each $4k + 1$ prime has *4* ways to be written as two *conjugate* gaussian primes
>    ($(p+qi)(p-qi), ~ (p-qi)(p+qi), ~ (q+pi)(q-pi), ~ (q-pi)(q+pi)$).
>  $2$ has two ways: $(1+i)(1-i)$ and $(1-i)(1+i)$.
>
>  Now suppose $x = p^2 + q^2$. That is equivalent to saying that $x = (p+qi)(p-qi)$. Therefore, we can take both halves of each (real) prime's conjugate factors, put one in $p+qi$, and the other in $p-qi$. And by the way, any powers of $4k + 3$ primes are outlawed; they can't make $p$ $q$ coprime.
>
>  But we don't want $p$ and $q$ to share factors. Suppose $p+qi = c(m+ni)$, where $c$ is real. Factor $c$. Since we shouldn't find real factors in each gaussian prime, so it must be the case that $c$ came from one of the following:
>
>    $(u + vi)(u - vi)$
>    $(u + vi)(v + ui)$
>
>  In other words, $m$ cannot co-exist with $\bar m$ or $i \bar m$. For $s = 4k +1$ prime powers, this is not a problem; just use the form $(p_s + q_s i)(p_s - q_s i)$ only and not the others, and put $p_s + q_s i$ into $p + qi$, and $p_s - q_s i$ into $p - qi$ and it's safe because $p_s$ and $q_s$ are not going to be the same.
>
>  Not so safe for 2. $1 + i$ can co-exist with neither $1 - i$ nor another $1 + i$. This means that once you have more than one $2$ to factor, you are not going to make it work.

After that, we have a somewhat boring part that combines everything we've deduced into a unified conclusion, as shown in first spoiler:

> For $n^2 \over p^2 + q^2$, we can, from 1, add in even powers of any prime, and take away any powers of $4k + 1$ primes and at most one $2$. Therefore:
>
>  • For $2$, we can add powers of $0$, $2$, $4$..., and may take or not take $1$.
>    Therefore, its power should be anything not less than $-1$.
>  • For $4k+1$ primes, we can basically add and take anything, so any integer prime is fine.
>  • For $4k+3$ primes, we can only add even powers, so the power should be non-negative and even.

Answer (score 5):

> Clearly, the segments that we draw must form two parallel lines in order to bound a square. Let us consider one set of these parallel lines. Since their endpoints are on integer coordinates, they can be expressed as $ax+by=c$ and $ax+by=d$ for integer $a,b,c,d$, where $a,b$ are coprime. The distance between these two lines can be computed to be $\frac{|c-d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$. Since the other pair of parallel lines must be equally spaced (for a square), the total area of the square is therefore $\frac{(c-d)^2}{a^2+b^2}$.
>  .
>  Now, let us now characterize all numbers that can be expressed of this form. In particular, the set of numbers that can be expressed in the form of $a^2+b^2$ (for $a,b$ coprime) is precisely those numbers which only have prime factors that are 1 mod 4, and 2. This result is due to Fermat. (We can multiply two expressible numbers using the identity $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2$). Therefore, numbers like $1.5 = \frac{3}{2}$ and $3$ cannot be areas of squares that we construct from this method, since $3$ has one prime factor that is 3 mod 4.
>  .
>  To show that we can get everything of the form $\frac{n^2}{a^2+b^2}$, it suffices to find integers such that $ax+by=1$ for coprime $a,b$, which we can find via Bezout. Then scale upward by a factor of $n$ to get our result.

Example

> $4/5 = \frac{2^2}{1^2+2^2}$, so we need to find $x,y$ such that $x+2y=2$. For instance, $(0,1)$ and $(2,0)$. We also need $x+2y=0$, for instance $(2,-1)$ and $(-2,1)$. Now we do the same for perpendicular lines $-2x+y=-2$ and $-2x+y=0$. For instance, $(0,-2)$ and $(2,2)$ and $(0,0)$, $(1,2)$ respectively. If some segments aren't long enough, you can extend them as needed. We can verify that this gives us the desired area. [image]

Comment: Can you provide some concrete examples as to how to derive different constructible numbers via your answer? e.g `1/2` and `4/5`. I don't think this answer's clear enough at its current state.

Comment: Your final answer looks good, but note that `In particular, the set of numbers that can be expressed in the form of a2+b2 (for a,b coprime) is precisely those numbers which only have prime factors that are 1 mod 4` is wrong (e.g `1^2 + 3^2 = 10 = 2 (mod 4)`). Please revise your proof before I can accept your answer ;-)